# не работает hover в css

Tags: html, css, hover

Посмотрел пару вопросов на эту тему, но ничего не помогло(с другого проекта скопировал и переписал значения, тоже не помогло)

Не смог найти ошибки, и решения проблемы тоже, заранее спасибо.

```css
.STDt {
  color: red;
  font-family: PointBold;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px lightgrey, 0 0 1em lightgrey, 0 0 0.2em lightgrey;
}

.STDt:hover {
  color: white;
  font-family: PointBold;
  font-size: 85px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px lightgrey, 0 0 1em lightgrey, 0 0 0.2em lightgrey;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p class="STDt">SunTimeDev</p>
```

!UPDATE  Немного изменил код, но текст также не меняется при hover

```
.STDt{
    line-height: 1.7;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url('../img/image3.jpg') center fixed;
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
    font-family: PointBold;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px lightgrey, 0 0 1em lightgrey, 0 0 0.2em lightgrey;
}
.STDt:hover{
    line-height: 1.7;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url('../img/image3.jpg') center fixed;
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 3px #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
     color: white;
    font-family: PointBold;
    font-size: 82px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px lightgrey, 0 0 1em lightgrey, 0 0 0.2em lightgrey;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

html:
`<p class="STDt">SunTimeDev</p>`
(Простите если что-то делаю не так, я новенький)

Comment: все работает, у вас стоял margin-top: -110px; - поменял на 0

Comment: В селекторе с :hover нужно указывать только изменяющие свойства. В данном случае это:
- font-size: 85px;
- text-decoration: underline;

Comment: Джефф, сделал, не помогло( .STDt:hover{ 
    font-size: 82px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
) @Джефф

Comment: Во-первых, не понятно зачем вы в `:hover` дублируете всё.. Во-вторых, не понятно в целом какая у вас задача и проблема - ховер работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при hover каждый раз не надо писать все значений пиши только при ховере font-size и text-decoration